# Ignite occur exception in Ubuntu VM when persistent: Too many open files

Tags: ignite

I run a server node in java code package xxx.jar, but occur exception like this:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /home/ranger/EIIP/tools/work/db/ServerNode/cache-TOFTableCache/part-942.bin: Too many open files
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newAsynchronousFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:196)
at java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel.open(AsynchronousFileChannel.java:248)
at java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel.open(AsynchronousFileChannel.java:301)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.AsyncFileIO.<init>(AsyncFileIO.java:66)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.AsyncFileIOFactory.create(AsyncFileIOFactory.java:44)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.FilePageStore.init(FilePageStore.java:523)
... 31 more
```

but only occured in ubuntu VM at windows, and no this exception when run at pure ubuntu system, I tried the following methods, but still the same problem：

```
vim /etc/security/limits.conf
root soft nofile 10240
root hard nofile 20480

vim /etc/sysctl.conf
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
ulimit -n 4096
```

this is my code:

```
        IgniteConfiguration igniteCfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        igniteCfg.setConsistentId("ServerNode"); //Set Consistent ID

        // Ignite Persistence
        DataStorageConfiguration storageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();
        DataRegionConfiguration regionCfg = new DataRegionConfiguration();
        regionCfg.setName("TableCache_Region");
        regionCfg.setInitialSize(100L * 1024 * 1024);
        regionCfg.setMaxSize(8L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
        regionCfg.setPersistenceEnabled(true);

        storageCfg.setDataRegionConfigurations(regionCfg);
        storageCfg.setPageSize(4096); // Changing the page size to 4 KB.
        storageCfg.setWriteThrottlingEnabled(true); // Enabling the writes throttling.

        igniteCfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(storageCfg);
        igniteCfg.setWorkDirectory(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/work"); // System.getProperty("java.class.path")

        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(igniteCfg);
        ignite.cluster().baselineAutoAdjustEnabled(false);

        // Activate a cluster automatically once all the nodes of the baseline topology have joined after a cluster restart.
        ignite.cluster().active(true);

        // Manually setting Baseline Topology
        Collection<ClusterNode> nodes = ignite.cluster().forServers().nodes();
        // Set all server nodes to baseline topology
        ignite.cluster().setBaselineTopology(nodes);
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?
Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah8vi.png)

Comment: How many nodes and caches do you have? I think you might try to increase the descriptors count even more and check the results

Comment: Thanks fou your reply, I have one server node like above and set persistentance, and then I start a client node to create cache and tables, in the client node I create 4 caches and 4 tables like below code:
```
dmsTableCache.put(dmsTableCache.sizeLong(), new DMSTable(dmsTableCache.sizeLong(), timeStamp, dmsKVCache));
```

Comment: It doesn't look like a lot, but I'd like to share the docs page in addition to the Anrei's answer https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/performance-tips#process-file-descriptor-limit

Comment: Thanks very much, I tried, but still the problems ...

Answer (score 1):

As I know to persists the ulimits values across reboots you should set it in the configuration file:

/etc/security/limits.conf

It contains **"soft"** and **"hard"** options. Hard options for root, soft for others.

Using **ulimit** command you can overwrite the **"soft"** values for current user and session. Probably your limits weren't stored or you set **"soft"** options but start the GridGain using sudo command and your **"hard"** options were incorrect.

Could you please double-check and provide the next information:

1)What operation system is used by you?

2)Do you have /etc/security/limits.conf file in your environment?

3)Do you have correct values for user that will start the Ignite. In case if you started it under root then check the "hard" options

However, I suggest to set the following options there:

```
ignite soft nofile 65536
ignite hard nofile 65536
ignite soft nproc 65536
ignite hard nproc 65536
```

Where **ignite** is the username that was used for Ignite starting.

Comment: Sometimes you require to restart the host. It can help to apply the new changes. Did you restart your hosts?

Comment: Yea, I restarted,,,I doubt whether it is the problem of virtual machine, after all, the official Ubuntu does not have this exception.

Comment: Or for some reason, the modification in the virtual machine does not take effect