# Apache Ignite terminate abruptly

Tags: c++, ignite

We are using Apache Ignite on our C++ application on a 32-bit ARM linux machine.

Our application is closing abruptly after certain number of entries in Database(4400 entries) and application is being terminated with "Buffer Overflow" error.

There is no other information in ignite logs or system logs. No dump file is also being generated. The below is all that we see in the log

```
*** buffer overflow detected 
***: /opt/XXX/XXXXx terminated
```

**When we disable the persistency there is no abrupt shutdown.**

We have also observed that while persistency is enabled and write operations are being performed on DB, there are too many files opened in `/proc/fd` for ignite and when the write operation is stopped also the number of files open is not decreasing.

My understanding is that these files should get closed by ignite after a certain time right?
Do you have any idea why it is happening ?
Also any help on "buffer overflow" issue?

Comment: This question as it now stands would probably be better on https://superuser.com/. Is "_Our application_" your own compiled code so you can add debug logs to it?

Comment: It is our own application. We compile the code.

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve]. As it is: Your code is triggering an error. We know the error, but we don't know your code.

Comment: Consider also breaking the problem into parts: for example, does pure Java application with persistence fail in the same scenario? Also, attach a C debugger and collect a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've encountered an issue with too many open files by a single user. Ignite required many open file descriptors to operate when persistence is enabled, since there is a file for every partition. So, if you have 10 partitioned caches on a one-node cluster, then it will need at least 10240 open file descriptors.

Try increasing the limits by running the following command:

```
ulimit -u 1000000
```

You can find more information in the following questions:

[Ignite occur exception in Ubuntu VM when persistent: Too many open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62208644/ignite-occur-exception-in-ubuntu-vm-when-persistent-too-many-open-files/62220058)

[Ignite node is failing with "Too many open files" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62458623/ignite-node-is-failing-with-too-many-open-files-error)

Comment: It is also possible that this is `poll` versus `select` issue since only one of them supports fd's larger than 1024 and they may both be used in C++ code.